# How to export a GPX file from OSMdroid?

Tags: export, kml, osmdroid, gpx, cartography

I would like to know how can we export a path that we generated on OSMdroid in GPX, KML or Shapefile?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OSMBonusPack, an add-on to osmdroid with [KML capabilities](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_4).

Comment: "14. Grab overlays in KML structure, save KML locally" Thank you for your answer @Mker